# What is the equivalent of Java Class in C#?

Tags: java, c#

In particular I'm referring to this piece of code, I'm trying to understand what it is doing in terms of the Class object.

In the code below what does Class mean?  Is it the same as 'Type' in C#?

Also what does the isSuperTypeOf() method doing in terms of 'Class type'?  The way they have written the method I don't know really which 'type' property is which.

Source of code in this document
[Dynamic Object Model](http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~pearce/oom/patterns/new/Riehle.pdf)

```
class PropertyType {

protected String name;

protected Class type;

protected boolean isMandatory;

...

public String getName() {

return name;

}

public boolean isSupertypeOf(Class type) {

return type.isAssignableFrom(type);

}

public boolean isValidValue(Object value) {

// check value, possibly delegate to a strategy

}

...

}
```

Comment: You're looking for the documentation.

Comment: in C# the type variable declaration being passed into the isSupertypeOf method would "hide" the declared type field in the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what does `Class` mean? Is it the same as `Type` in C#?

Yes, `System.Type` of .NET is a close equivalent of Java `java.lang.Class`.

> Also what does the `isSuperTypeOf()` method doing in terms of `Class type`?

`isSuperTypeOf` method provides a wrapper for the `isAssignableFrom` method. Its equivalent in C# is, not surprisingly, [`IsAssignableFrom`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `System.Type`.

Perhaps the biggest difference between the `Class` of Java and the `Type` of .NET is that `Class` is *generic* on the type that it represents, while `Type` is not a generic class. The reason behind this difference has to do with the difference in the way the generics of Java and .NET are implemented: Java's implementation is based on type erasure, so having `Class` be generic provides certain benefits that are unnecessary under .NET's implementation scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the closest analogy in C# is Type. In the sense that it represents the metadata about the object's type. However there are many differences between Java and C# reflection mechanisms.